# How to execute a (click) function for ALL found elements in parallel?

Tags: click, handler

Assume a webpage contains MULTIPLE elements with classname "accordion__indicator". Each of the is connect with teh same event handler opening a drop down textbox.

When I click manually on one element to open the drag down then a possibly open other element is automatically closed. So the the eventhandler allows by default only 1 open drag down clickable element at a time.

I could perform from within a script a jQuery function on the whole webpage like

$('.accordion__indicator').click();

Unfortunately jQuery steps through all occurrences, opens them together with a close of the previous element. This way only the last element is open at the end.

How can I open ALL element in parallel?
I guess I have to fool the event handler and prevent telling him that I opened a second, third,.... element.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could possible have a onClick event and for each element which invokes a function. When the form loads your click the first one using the addEventListener and then its onClick event clicks the next element. So in the example below button1's onClick will be click2(). Each element needs a unique id.

```
        <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", afterLoaded,false);

        function afterLoaded(){                             
                            document.getElementById("button1").click();
                      <!-- click2(); would cascade the clicks -->
                              } 
        function click2(){                          
                          document.getElementById("button2").click();
                          }                                   
        </script>
```